# How to add comments to an Exuberant Ctags config file?

Tags: comments, warnings, ctags, exuberant-ctags

What character can I use to put comments in an Exuberant Ctags `.ctags` file?

I would like to add comments with explanations, and perhaps to disable some regexps.

But I can't find any comment character which ctags-exuberant accepts!
I keep getting the warning:

```
ctags: Warning: Ignoring non-option in /home/joey/.ctags
```

which is better than an error, but still a little annoying.

I have tried `#` `//` `/* ... */` and `;` as comments, but ctags tries to parse them all!

Here is an example file with some comments which ctags will complain about:

```
# Add some more rules for Javascript
--langmap=javascript:+.jpp
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*var ([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*).*$/\1/v,variable/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*this\.([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)[ \t]*=.*$/\1/e,export/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*):.*$/\1/p,property/
--regex-javascript=/^\<function\>[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)/\1/f,function/

# Define tags for the Coffeescript language
--langdef=coffee
--langmap=coffee:.coffee
--regex-coffee=/^class @?([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)( extends [a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)?$/\1/c,class/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*(@|this\.)([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*).*$/\2/e,export/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*@?([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*):.*[-=]>.*$/\1/f,function/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)[ \t]+=.*[-=]>.*$/\1/f,function/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)[ \t]+=[^->\n]*$/\1/v,variable/
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*@?([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*):.*$/\1/p,property/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @joeytwiddle points out, comments are not supported by the parser, but there is a work-around.

Example `.ctags` file:

```
--regex-C=/$x/x/x/e/ The ctags parser currently doesn't support comments
--regex-C=/$x/x/x/e/ This is a work-around which works with '/' characters
--regex-C=/$x/x/x/e/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973224/how-to-add-comments-to-an-exuberant-ctags-config-file
--regex-C=/$x/x/x/e/ 
--regex-C=/$x/x/x/e/ You can add whatever comment text you want here.
```

Answer (score 32):

You can't!  I looked through the source code (thanks to apt-get source).  There are no checks for lines to ignore.  The relevant code is in parseFileOptions() in options.c

But sometimes comments are a neccessity, so as a workaround I put a comment in as a regexp, in such as way that it is unlikely to ever match anything.

```
--regex-coffee=/^(COMMENT: Disable next line when using prop tag)/\1/X,XXX/
```

The `^` helps the match to fail quickly, whilst the `(` `)` wrapper is purely for visual effect.

Your comment should be a valid regexp, to avoid warnings on stderr. (That means unescaped `/`s must be avoided, and if you use any `[` `]` `(` or `)`s they should be paired up.)  See Tom's solution to avoid these restrictions.

Comment: +1 for looking through the source code. The hackish solution is rather ugly though, I'd rather live with the warnings.

Comment: Can we suggest the support for comments on the development team?

Comment: **Note** this solution fails if there is a `/` in between the `(` and `)`. See my answer for something that works with this and looks visually neater.

Answer (score 4):

You can use '#' as the start of comment if you are using Universal-ctag(https://ctags.io).

Answer (score 1):

Given that comments don't work, what about a `.ctags.readme` file...

For most things you don't actually need a comment, e.g. you don't really need the comment below.

```
# Define tags for the Coffeescript language
--langdef=coffee
--langmap=coffee:.coffee
```

I can see however that you might want to add comments explaining some mind bending regex, so for each line that absolutely needs it you can copy paste it into the `.ctags.readme` file as a markdown file:

````
Forgive me father for I have regexed
It was purely because I wanted some lovely coffee properties
```
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*@?([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*):.*$/\1/p,property/
```
````

#### Keeping `.ctags.readme` and `.ctags` in sync

You could have a block at the bottom of the ctags file separated with a line break, then delete this final block.

If you only have the one line break in your `.ctags` file this sed will delete all the lines after the line break.

Then do some grepping for the `--regex` lines to append the lines from `.ctags.readme` into `.ctags`.

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/,$d' .ctags
grep "^--regex" .ctags.readme >> .ctags
```