# Does universal-ctags support exuberant-ctags config files?

Tags: exuberant-ctags

I've got a `$HOME/.ctags` file from [exuberant-tags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), but [universal-tags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) doesn't seem to be picking up my options from it. Does universal-tags support these config files?

Answer (score 13):

See [this documentation](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/blob/master/docs/optlib.rst) for details. The quick answer is:

```
mkdir $HOME/.ctags.d
mv $HOME/.ctags $HOME/.ctags.d/default.ctags
```

As an added bonus, you can now [add comments to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856815/622049).

Comment: love uctags but this bit really wasn't worth changing!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the file must have a name. at least in windows. so
`.ctags` will never work. As soon as I renamed my file to `defaults.ctags` the executable started reading it, if you enter bad syntax in the ctags file you will see errors output on the command line.